# string formating - replacing code in php

Tags: php, string

I want a string replacing code

i have a string like this

```
<strong>WHAT IS YOUR BIRTH DATE?</strong><br />
WE BEGIN THE GREATEST JOURNEY OF OUR LIFE AT THE MOMENT OF OUR BIRTH. OUR
VIBRATIONAL PATTERNS ARE THEN SET IN MOTION. THEY ARE FIXED AND
UNCHANGEABLE, NOT LIKE YOUR NAME WHICH CAN BE CHANGED AT ANY TIME DURING
YOUR LIFE. YOUR DATE OF BIRTH NUMBER OFFERS AMAZING INSIGHTS INTO YOUR
CHARACTER, PERSONALITY, AND INDIVIDUALITY. WHEN MATCHED WITH ANOTHER
HAVING THE SAME VIBRATIONAL PATTERN, YOUR OUTLOOK AND APPROACH TO LIFE
WILL BE SIMILAR. YOU WILL FIND MORE HARMONY AND COMPATIBILITY WHICH
STRENGTHENS THE BOND AND BRINGS MORE HAPPINESS.<br /><br />
```

i want to identify the tags and my resultant string to be stored in two variables like this

```
string 1 = WHAT IS YOUR BIRTH DATE?

string 2 = WE BEGIN THE GREATEST JOURNEY OF OUR LIFE AT THE MOMENT OF OUR
BIRTH. OUR VIBRATIONAL PATTERNS ARE THEN SET IN MOTION. THEY ARE FIXED AND
UNCHANGEABLE, NOT LIKE YOUR NAME WHICH CAN BE CHANGED AT ANY TIME DURING
YOUR LIFE. YOUR DATE OF BIRTH NUMBER OFFERS AMAZING INSIGHTS INTO YOUR
CHARACTER, PERSONALITY, AND INDIVIDUALITY. WHEN MATCHED WITH ANOTHER
HAVING THE SAME VIBRATIONAL PATTERN, YOUR OUTLOOK AND APPROACH TO LIFE
WILL BE SIMILAR. YOU WILL FIND MORE HARMONY AND COMPATIBILITY WHICH
STRENGTHENS THE BOND AND BRINGS MORE HAPPINESS.
```

is there a way i can replace do this in php

is there any string replacing code in php to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).